# Why does order matter when overriding @abstractmethods in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class

Why does base class order matter when overriding @abstractmethods in base classes?
Is it possible to override abstract methods in base classes without depending on base class order?

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def f(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class B:
    def f(self):
        pass

# class C(A,B): pass  # fails
class C(B,A): pass  # works
```

While `C(B,A)` works, `C(A,B)` results in

`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods f`

Comment: Thanks, but still fails for me :-/

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question with failure conditions and error message.